# Sort a file in unix by the absolute value of a field

Tags: sorting, unix, awk

I want to sort this file by the **absolute** value of the Linear regression (p) column in descending order. My attempt to do this didnt quite work. Im not sure what it fails. I found this code from http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/168144-sort-absolute-value.html.

```
awk -F',' '{print ($2>=0)?$2:-$2, $0}' OFS=',' mycsv1.csv | sort -n -k8,8 | cut -d ',' -f2-



X var,Y var,MIC (strength),MIC-p^2 (nonlinearity),MAS (non-monotonicity),MEV (functionality),MCN (complexity),Linear regression (p)
AT1G01030,AT1G32310,0.67958,0.4832027,0.32644996,0.63247,4.0,-0.44314474
AT1G01030,AT3G06520,0.61732,0.17639545,0.23569,0.58557,4.0,0.6640215
AT1G01030,AT5G42580,0.61579,0.5019064,0.30105,0.58143,4.0,0.33746648
AT1G01030,AT1G55280,0.57287,0.20705527,0.19536,0.52857,4.0,0.6048262
AT1G01030,AT5G30490,0.56509,0.37536618,0.16172999,0.51847,4.0,-0.43557298
AT1G01030,AT1G80040,0.56268,0.22935495,0.18583998,0.52728,4.0,-0.5773431
...
```

Please help me to understand the awk script to sort this file.

Comment: What is 'didn't quite work'?

Comment: . It didnt sort by column 8 or any other column. so Im not sure why it fails

Comment: A little closer look at the code should have helped here. I mean why are you looking at field `$2` in `awk`, when you are interested in the 8th field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sed` and `sort` for this and follow the @hek2mgl's very smart logic of adding and removing a field at the end to retain the original number:

```
 sed -E 's/,([-]?)([0-9.]+)$/,\1\2,\2/' file | sort -t, -k9,9 -nr | cut -f1-8 -d,
```

- `sed -E 's/,([-]?)([0-9.]+)$/,\1\2,\2/'` => creates field 9 as the absolute value of field 8
- `sort -t, -k9,9 -nr` => sorts by the newly created field, numeric and descending order
- `cut -f1-8 -d,` => removes the 9th field, restoring the output to its original format, with the desired sorting order

Here is the output:

```
AT1G01030,AT3G06520,0.61732,0.17639545,0.23569,0.58557,4.0,0.6640215
AT1G01030,AT1G55280,0.57287,0.20705527,0.19536,0.52857,4.0,0.6048262
AT1G01030,AT1G80040,0.56268,0.22935495,0.18583998,0.52728,4.0,-0.5773431
AT1G01030,AT1G32310,0.67958,0.4832027,0.32644996,0.63247,4.0,-0.44314474
AT1G01030,AT5G30490,0.56509,0.37536618,0.16172999,0.51847,4.0,-0.43557298
AT1G01030,AT5G42580,0.61579,0.5019064,0.30105,0.58143,4.0,0.33746648
```

Comment: If you output the default separator for sort and cut (\t) instead of , from the first command then you don't need to specify those in the later commands.

Answer (score 0):

Take three steps:

(1) Temporarily create a 9th field which contains the abs value of field 8:

```
LC_COLLATE=C awk -F, 'NR>1{v=$NF;sub(/-/,"",v);printf "%s%s%s%s",$0,FS,v,RS}' file
        ^ ------ make sure this is set since sorting, especially the decimal point
             depends on the local.
```

(2) Sort that output based on the 9th field:

```
command_1 | sort -t, -k9r
```

(3) Pipe that back to awk to remove the last field. `NF--` decreases the number of fields which will effectively remove the last field. `1` is always true, that makes `awk` print the line:

```
command_2 | cut -d, -f1-8
```

Output:

```
AT1G01030,AT3G06520,0.61732,0.17639545,0.23569,0.58557,4.0,0.6640215
AT1G01030,AT1G55280,0.57287,0.20705527,0.19536,0.52857,4.0,0.6048262
AT1G01030,AT1G80040,0.56268,0.22935495,0.18583998,0.52728,4.0,-0.5773431
AT1G01030,AT1G32310,0.67958,0.4832027,0.32644996,0.63247,4.0,-0.44314474
AT1G01030,AT5G30490,0.56509,0.37536618,0.16172999,0.51847,4.0,-0.43557298
AT1G01030,AT5G42580,0.61579,0.5019064,0.30105,0.58143,4.0,0.33746648
```

Comment: also, you should set `LC_COLLATE` instead of `LANG` to avoid other possible unwanted side-effects of changing the locale.

Comment: Since the number of columns is know, `cut` might be the better alternative to `awk` then. Changed that and using `LC_COLLATE` now.

Answer (score 0):

Could get awk to do it all:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{n[substr($NF,1,1)=="-"?substr($NF,2):$NF]=$0}NR==1;END{asorti(n,out);for(i in out)print n[out[i]]}' file
```